# Using an if/else statement in the middle of AWK

Tags: linux, awk

I have a 5-column file:

```
PS 6 15 0 1
PS 1 17 0 1
PS 4 18 0 1
```

that I would like to get it in this 7-column format:

```
PS.15 PS 6 N 1 0 1
PS.17 PS 1 P 1 0 1
PS.18 PS 4 N 1 0 1
```

To create 6 of the 7 columns requires just grabbing directly (and sometimes applying small arithmetic) from columns in the original file. However, to create one column (column 4) requires an if-else statement.

Specifically, to create new columns 1, 2, 3, I use:

```
 cat File | awk '{print $1"."$3"\t"$1"\t"$2}'
```

and to create new columns 5, 6,7, I use:

```
 cat testFileB | awk '{print $4+$5"\t"$4/($4+$5)"\t"$5/($4+$5)}'
```

and to create new column 4, I use:

```
 cat testFileB | awk '{if ($2 == 1 || $2 == 2 || $2 == 3) print "P"; else print "N";}'
```

These three statements work fine independently and get me what I want (the correct values for the columns that are all separated by tabs). However, when I try to apply them simultaneously (create all 7 columns at once), I can only do so with unwanted new lines (instead of tabs) before and after column 4 (the if/else statement column):

For instance, my attempt to simultaneously create columns 1, 2, 3, 4:

```
 cat File | awk '{print $1"."$3"\t"$1"\t"$2; if ($2 == 1 || $2 == 2 || $2 == 3) print "P"; else print "N";}'
```

results in unwanted new lines before column 4:

```
PS.15 PS 6
N
PS.17 PS 1
P
PS.18 PS 4
```

Similarly, my attempt to simultaneously create columns 4, 5, 6, 7:

```
 cat File | awk '{if ($2 == 1 || $2 == 2 || $2 == 3) print "P"; else print "N"; print $4+$5"\t"$4/($4+$5)"\t"$5/($4+$5)}'
```

results in unwanted new lines after column 4:

```
N
1 0 1
P
1 0 1
N
1 0 1
```

Is there a solution so that I can create all 7 columns at once, and there are only tabs between them (no new lines)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want automatic line feeds, you can just use `printf` instead of `print`. I'm not quite sure if you want a tab separating the `N1` or not, but that's easy enough to adjust;

```
cat testfile | awk '{printf "%s.%s\t%s\t%s\t",$1,$3,$1,$2; if ($2 == 1 || $2 == 2 || $2 == 3) printf "P"; else printf "N"; print $4+$5"\t"$4/($4+$5)"\t"$5/($4+$5)}'

PS.15   PS  6   N1  0   1
PS.17   PS  1   P1  0   1
PS.18   PS  4   N1  0   1
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I had been puzzled after searching :o)

Comment: Lose the [useless use of `cat`](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html), though.

Answer (score 1):

Simply set your OFS (instead of repeating a `\t` all across the line), and use the ternary operator to print P or N:

```
$ awk -v OFS='\t' '{s=$4+$5;print $1"."$3,$1,$2,($2~/^[123]$/?"P":"N"),s,$4/s,$5/s}' file
PS.15   PS      6       N       1       0       1
PS.17   PS      1       P       1       0       1
PS.18   PS      4       N       1       0       1
```